# How to get the value of a HTML slider inside a servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

If I am using a HTML slider, how can I get the value of the position at which it is present, in a servlet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a JavaScript code in the HTML page that sends the slider position to the server when the slider moves. Then the servlet can process these requests and use it for whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is asked here[Servlet return value: JQuery Ajax request](http://www.coderanch.com/t/469356/Servlets/java/Servlet-return-JQuery-Ajax-request)

What has been said is correct you would need to have some javascript code that looks something like:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "../slider",
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                position: position,
            },
            success : function(answer){

                }
            }
```

If you post your code we may be able to assist more.